# Iterate over page.evaluate in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, puppeteer

I'm trying to using `for`-`of` looping method to iterate an array of URLs and use them with `page.evaluate` (puppeteer library) function. I will post a snippet of my code (single URL version) so one person here can explain to me better how to loop that. I'd like to define an array of urls (maybe defined in a Json) to use instead of replace the second url every time i want to switch between my school subjects

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://marconi-pr.registroelettronico.com/quaderno/'); //go to login page
await page.waitFor(2000);
await page.click('#ext-container-6 > div.x-size-monitors.scroll'); //skip some ads
await page.waitFor(2000);
await page.type('#ext-element-21', 'user'); //user field
await page.waitFor(1000);
await page.type('#ext-element-27', 'password'); //pwd field
await page.click('#btnAccedi'); //login button
await page.waitFor(5000);
await page.goto('https://marconi-pr.registroelettronico.com/mastercom/register_manager.php?_dc=1537450418307&id_materia=1000188&action=get_assignments_subject&page=1&start=0&limit=25'); //after login i want to access this
const html = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await page.$('pre')); //copying some things
await browser.close();
return html;
};

scrape().then((html) => {
html = JSON.parse(html); //parsing as json
console.log(html); // Success!
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) on an array of URLs after logging in using the following method:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const urls = [
  'https://www.example.com/page-1',
  'https://www.example.com/page-2',
  'https://www.example.com/page-3',
];

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  let result = '';

  await page.goto('https://www.example.com/login');

  await page.type('#username', 'username');
  await page.type('#password', 'password');

  await page.click('#submit');

  await page.waitForNavigation();

  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    await page.goto(urls[i]);

    result = await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementById('example').innerHTML);

    console.log(result);
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Many thanks I will try surely. The part of code I need is the for() right?